# Proof that cross product is orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, orthogonality, cross-product

I'm trying to prove that (u x v) is orthogonal to both u and v. Is it a sufficient proof to simply demonstrate that the dot product of u and (u x v) is equal to zero because due to the properties of the cross product, the previous expression is equivalent to the dot product of (u x u) and v. Since the cross product of u with itself is obviously 0, we can see that u is orthogonal to (u x v). I would repeat this same process for v.

Is that a sufficient proof?

Comment: Yes that is sufficient. If you want to ask more questions here please learn to write the mathematics using mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Ok, got it. thank you.

Comment: What specific properties of the cross product are you using? I am guessing it is $ u \cdot (v \times w) = (u \times v) \cdot w $. If so, please explicitly cite it.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I will be sure to cite it next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The logic is valid. Since $x \cdot (y \times z) = z \cdot (x \times y)$, and $x \times x = 0$ for all $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}^3$, we do indeed have $u \cdot (u \times v) = v \cdot (u \times v) = 0$.

The question of whether the proof is sufficent or not depends a little on context. I'm guessing that you're taking some kind of course? If so, make sure you're allowed to use these facts. Specifically, check to see if they're in the lecture notes. Many lecturers don't like it when you pull facts off the internet in an introductory course.

Comment: Ah I see. This is indeed a question relating to a course I am taking. It's a good point to cross-check with the lecture notes. Thank you.