# A problem with cross product of two vectors

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, cross-product

Problem:

> Let $u$ and $v$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Can $u \times v$ be a non-zero
> scalar multiple of $u$?

Answer:

Recall that:
$$ u \times v = (u_2 v_3 - u_3 v_2)i + (u_3v_1 - u_1 v_3)j +  (u_1 v_2 - u_2 v_1)k $$
Since $u \times v$ is perpendicular to $u$ and $v$ then I believe the statement is false. I will now attempt a more rigours proof.

Suppose the statement is true. We have a $K$ such that
$u \times v = Ku$ where $u$, $v$ and $K$ are non-zero. Then
$$(u_2 v_3 - u_3 v_2)i + (u_3v_1 - u_1 v_3)j +  (u_1 v_2 - u_2 v_1)k
 = K(u_1,u_2,u_3)$$
that is
$$
\begin{cases} 
u_2 v_3 - u_3 v_2 = K u_1 \\
u_3 v_1 - u_1 v_3 = K u_2 \\
u_1 v_2 - u_2 v_1 = K u_3 \\
\end{cases}$$
Now I am struck. Am on the right track?

Comment: Multiple your relations with $u_1$, $u_2$ and $u_3$ respectively. After adding them you will get $0=K(u_1^2+u_2^2+u_3^2)$.

Comment: @JensSchwaiger I am not following your last comment. Which equation(s) are you referring to?

Comment: $u=0$ works but if $u\ne 0$ then $u\cdot (u\times v)=0$ but $u\cdot ku=k\lVert u\rVert^2$.

Comment: I refer to these equations: $u_2 v_3 - u_3 v_2 = K u_1,
u_3 v_1 - u_1 v_3 = K u_2 ,
u_1 v_2 - u_2 v_1 = K u_3 
$.

Comment: @JensSchwaiger Are you saying that I should compute: (u_2 v_3 - u_3 v_2) (u_3 v_1 - u_1 v_3)(u_1 v_2 - u_2 v_1) ? I tired doing that using an online calculator and I got a mess. Should it work out to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wirsing this as another comment is too cumbersome. So I write an answer.
Using
\begin{cases} 
u_2 v_3 - u_3 v_2 = K u_1 \\
u_3 v_1 - u_1 v_3 = K u_2 \\
u_1 v_2 - u_2 v_1 = K u_3 \\
\end{cases}
we  multiply the first equation by $u_1$, the second by $u_2$
and the last one by $u_3$ and add these the equations. Then  the righthand side equals $K(u_1^2+u_2^2+u_3^2)$. The lefthand side  equals $(u_2 v_3 - u_3 v_2) u_1+(u_3 v_1 - u_1 v_3)u_2+(u_1 v_2 - u_2 v_1 )u_3
$, which turns out to be 0. So also $K(u_1^2+u_2^2+u_3^2)=0$. Since $K\not=0$ by assumption we have $u_1^2+u_2^2+u_3^2=0$. This implies that $u_1=u_2=u_3=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The cross-product of two vectors are orthogonal to these vectors. See [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2880848/proof-that-cross-product-is-orthogonal). If, $u\times v=Ku$ where $K\neq 0$, then
$$u\cdot Ku=u\cdot(u\times v)$$
$$K||u||^2=0$$
$$||u||=0$$
$$u=0.$$
Therefore, $u\times v$ can be a non-zero scalar multiple of $u$ iff $u$ is zero vector.